# drools workbench guided rule to include multiple rules in one file

Tags: drools, rules, rule-engine, kie-workbench

I am working on a Drools project which includes many many rules. We use Drools rules for validation. There are many fields and various combinations of errors.  In Drools workbench 6.4.0,  we use Guided Rules (with DSL) wizard to provide the business friendly UI to create rule. The problem is each new Guided Rule action will allow you to create only one rule, and it's saved as one rule file, a .rdslr file.

If I manually create the drools rules, I can simply group them together, like 10 or 20 rules,  into one rule file. Using the web guided rule UI, is there a way I can add new rule to the existing guided rule file?   Otherwise, I will have to create a rule file for each rule, ending up with huge number of rule files, very hard to navigate in web UI.

If I have to keep each rule in its own rule file, is there limit for the number of rule files? Is there is performance concern?

Answer (score 2):

> If I manually create the drools rules, I can simply group them together, like 10 or 20 rules, into one rule file. Using the web guided rule UI, is there a way I can add new rule to the existing guided rule file? Otherwise, I will have to create a rule file for each rule, ending up with huge number of rule files, very hard to navigate in web UI.

If the when conditions are nearly the same, I suggest using the Guided Decision Table.  One row is one rule.

> If I have to keep each rule in its own rule file, is there limit for the number of rule files?

Practical limit, not really - thousands are easily possible with proper computer hardware (CPU, RAM).

> Is there is performance concern?

With multiple rule files, no.  At startup, Drools processes the rules into internally cached tables, so the end result is effectively the same regardless of the original rule format (e.g. one large rule file, all in separate rule files).

Regarding performance concern on rule organization, depends more on rule quantity.  The runtime performance is still very good with lots of rules.  As expected, I notice a longer build time with more rules in the system but not any execution slowness.

But rule quantity has never been the problem I've seen.  Poor rules architecture is the key performance and maintenance problem, not rule quantity.

Comment: Unfortunately, decision table doesn't support DSL, and most of our validation rules cannot be expressed by the default set of operators. I don't see the support of simple example like a field of max length. I wish user can type in the  number in the row, then we can build a rule like myfield.length() > maxLength, then add error code.

Comment: The Guided Decision Table has a lot of weaknesses/lacking features.  Two things regarding that: 1. Use BRL or DRL condition or action as it allows coding the needed snippet; 2. Use a spreadsheet for the full power of decision tables and upload it.  I've found power end users adapt to the decision table well and love it.  No DSL needed.  Lastly, your last statement means you should consider Drools Templates.  They do that nicely - define a spreadsheet for the data only (1 row is 1 rule's data) and create a template rule (a parameterized rule) that generates one rule per spreadsheet row.

Comment: can we achieve this by extending other rules in guided rule editor?

Comment: How can we actually use rule template in kie workbench?